# Расширение для встроенного php -S localhost:XXXX сервера mysqli

Tags: php, localhost, консоль, extension

Постепенно перехожу с Win на Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
В обычной повседневной практике скрипты запускаю встроенным сервером PHP, apache и nginx стараюсь не использовать на локальном.
Но встроенному в PHP web-серверу не хватает расширений curl/pdo/ и т.д
В конфиге php.ini можно поправить/раскомментировать (и получать ошибки в консоли на их отсутствие),  но как сами расширения найти и закинуть, понимаю что example.dll Ubuntu не воспримет.
Для web-серверов apache и nginx как бы вопрос решаемый, но вот как быть со встроенным PHP web-сервером как их поддтянуть?
Спасибо!

Comment: расширения же вы подключаете в php.ini, а не в апаче или nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Этот встроенный сервер это просто часть вашего php. То есть расширений нет не для сервера, а для php в целом. Для убунты есть пакеты, которые устанавливают расширения. Вы уже освоили [apt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)? Наберите `apt-cache search php curl`, `apt-cache show php-curl`. Чтобы установить: `sudo apt-get install php-curl`.

PDO вроде идёт из коробки, надо только поставить драйвер для mysql: `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` (или какая у вас база).

Comment: База mysql, apt закрепляется)))  Вот сама то и магия, как эти пакеты связать с php. Логически понимаю так: в php.ini снимаю комментарий модуля/расширения и подгружаю пакет  sudo apt-get install php-curl в ... директорию где находится хотя бы один пакет по умолчанию (из коробки), например  pdo/json. А вот за apt-cache search и show отдельное спасибо, не сталкивался пока что.

Comment: @GennadyGА в убунте немного другая конфигурация. Там инклюдятся конфиги из conf.d. А там они просто ссылки на конфиги из mods_available. Сразу после установки модуль автоматически подключается -- создаётся ссылка в conf.d. Редактировать php.ini не надо. Если что, включать и выключать уже установленные модули можно через phpenmod и phpdismod.

Answer (score 0):

Резюмируя (при поддержке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/242216/%d0%95%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bd):

 Для Ubuntu 20

1. Как обычно php-cli в консоли покажет подключенные расширения (php -m).
2. Для недостающих расширений или тех которых нет из коробки, например mysqli-client, soap или других есть команда Linux (она же bash): sudo apt install mysqli-client.
3. В Linux не надо лезть в php.ini для раскомментирования расширений, не переживайте все установится Linux автоматически!